# Problem with sending postmessage, sendmessage etc other apis to x11 forwarded window

Tags: c++, windows, x11, sendmessage, postmessage

I am trying to create a mirroring tool in c++ which takes keyboard input using getch() in a while loop and then sends it to the windows which I desire.

I am using the approach mentioned here to send the keystrokes which works fine for some windows - https://cplusplus.com/forum/windows/58966/#msg318288

But, it doesn't work for a process which is running on a linux machine through putty and the windows is forwarded using x11.
Is there any specific reason for that? Is there a way to send the keystrokes to such windows? Please note that the target window doesn't have any children window.